# sql server database diagram

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I created a database mdf file a while back and created a diagram of foreign keys. Lately, I needed to add several tables and there was an error saying I couldn't do the diagram because I'm not the owner.

So, I didn't update the diagram but added the tables anyway. My app seems to be working fine with the new tables. I'm using linq-to-sql and the design surface of the ORM doesn't show the connection between the new and the old tables.

My question is this: if the app works both with and without the diagram, what's the benefit of creating one? I know I can read an 800-page book and get the answer but I was wondering what the 2-3 line answer would be.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of handy uses for diagrams.  When creating a database it can be a quick way to set up tables and create the relations.  When visiting a database that you haven't met, it can be a quick way to get an overview.  Tip: You can cut and paste blocks of columns.  A handy way to set up similar tables, e.g. copying all of the fields for a street address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagram is just modeling tool.. no need to use it, but cool to visualise db, easier to write queries if you're not creator of db.

You can switch owner of db in options at "File" tab.

Comment: Does creating the diagram create foreign key relationships or is it really just purely visual?

Comment: @frenchie - The diagram is live.  Changes made elsewhere will be reflected in the diagram, at least when it is refreshed.  Changes to the diagram update the database when the diagram is saved.